Time labels in Y Axis in C# chart
I'm trying to show accumulated time in a serie of a column chart. This "time" is given in seconds (int), but for a better understanding, I need to show it in "hh:mm:ss" format.
Is there a way to configure the Y axis to show "00:00", "01:00" , "02:00 ... " instead of the int value ?

